# Setup multiple Raspberry Pi different network configurations

Tags: ansible, deployment, chef, raspberry-pi-os

For multiple projects we are setting up 2 to 6 RPi's per project. Each project runs on a different network and for some of these networks we can use DHCP, for others the RPi's have to connect using a static IP address.

Also every RPi needs a different hostname in sequential order. For instance for a project with three RPi's, the hostnames need to be PROCCESS1, PROCESS2, PROCESS3.

All RPi's run the exact same software and every RPi has a single monitor connected.

The current workflow is:

1. Burn a prepared OS image for every RPi on a microSD
2. Boot up the RPi using the microSD and manually set the hostname
3. If needed, set the IP address to a static one
4. Turn on the overlay file system so the system is read-only
5. Repeat for the amount of RPi's needed

This is a tedious task where errors are made and takes a lot of time. Step 1 can not be automated, since we don't have the hardware (altough the EtcherPro would eventually save a lot of time). Automating step 3 and 4 would be great if that can be realized. I've read a bit about Ansible and also encountered Chef and Puppet but I haven't dived into any of them yet.

Is using Ansible with playbooks a good direction to develop further? Would it be possible to automate the setup using this tool? Is there a better/easier solution or would it not be possible at all? If someone has some tips or can guide in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even without Ansible or other config management tool, there's no
reason any of those steps need to be manual: you could drive
everything with a shell script, thus reaping all the benefits of
automation: no more errors, consistent deployments, and faster
configuration. Using Ansible can help make the process more modular
and more structured, but it doesn't fundamentally allow you to do
anything new.

---

Ignoring the question of what tooling you use to drive the
configuration, I'd like to suggest an option that you may not have
considered: it's possible to perform all the configuration on the image *before* burning it onto a microsd card. You can mount the raspberry pi os image on a local directory, and then make all your configuration changes there. I use a process like this:

1. Download and unzip the raspberry pi os image
2. Make a working copy of the image (this way you can re-use the base
   image multiple times to create different configured images):

   ```
   # cp 2022-01-28-raspios-bullseye-armhf-lite.img work.img
   ```

   I like to extend the image a bit so there's room for installing
   new software:

   ```
   # truncate -s 2500MB work.img
   ```
3. Attach the work image to a loop device:

   ```
   # losetup -fnP --show work.img
   /dev/loop0
   ```
4. Grow the filesystem to use the additional space:

   ```
   # parted /dev/loop0 resizepart 2 100%
   # e2fsck -f /dev/loop0p2
   # resize2fs /dev/loop0p2
   ```
5. Mount the filesystems locally:

   ```
   # mount /dev/loop0p2 /mnt
   # mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/boot
   ```

---

Now you're in a position where you can create and modify configuration
files on the image, in order to...

- Configure networking
- Configure the hostname
- Enable ssh
- Configure wifi
- Install ssh keys
- Etc.

But what if you want to do other things, like update or install
packages? If you install the `qemu-user-static` package and properly
configure the `binfmt_misc` module (modern versions of the
`qemu-user-static` package will do this for you automatically), you will be
able to run Raspberry Pi binaries on your host. This allows you to run
commands inside the image, like this:

```
# systemd-nspawn -D /mnt apt update
# systemd-nspawn -D /mnt apt upgrade -y
# systemd-nspawn -D /mnt apt install -y git
```

Or inject a shell script:

```
# systemd-nspawn -D /mnt --bind=$PWD/config.sh:/config.sh sh /config.sh
```

Here I'm using `systemd-nspawn`, which is a little like `chroot` (in
this example), except it takes care of mounting special
filesystems like /sys and /proc and has all sorts of interesting
options (like the `--bind` option for bind mounting files or
directories into the image).

---

When you're all done, unmount the filesystem and disconnect the loop
device:

```
# umount /mnt/boot /mnt
# losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

And write the customized image to an sd card:

```
# dd if=work.img of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
```

---

You can wrap the entire process described here in a script, and have
it take parameters to configure networking (specify a static address
or use dhcp), etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this is very useful.